# VBA Excel - Cannot use that command on overlapping selections

Tags: excel, vba

My code appears to work, but it highlights my last row of code and says, "Run-time error '1004': Cannot use that command on overlapping selections."

I've tried some various changes I found online, but I can't seem to fix the error.

```
Sub Delete_EEE()

Dim Wrds As Variant, Gwrds As Variant, i As Long, Fnd As Range, fAdr As String

Gwrds = Array("jan", "m123", "06014", "06015", "06016", "t49", "m39", "cwr", "rnc", "d55", "rer", "rlr", "rwr", "M55", "5962")

Wrds = Array("ohm", "resistor", "semiconductor", "MCKT", "MICKT", "microcircuit", "inductor", "xfmr", "eeprom", "oscillator")

'Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LBound(Gwrds) To UBound(Gwrds)
    Set Fnd = Range("G:G").Find(Gwrds(i), , , xlPart, , , False)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        fAdr = Fnd.Address
        Fnd.Value = "#N/A"
        Do
            Set Fnd = Range("G:G").FindNext(Fnd)
            If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Fnd.Address = fAdr Then Exit Do
            Fnd.Value = "#N/A"
        Loop
    End If
Next i

For i = LBound(Wrds) To UBound(Wrds)
    Set Fnd = Range("E:E").Find(Wrds(i), , , xlPart, , , False)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        fAdr = Fnd.Address
        Fnd.Value = "#N/A"
        Do
            Set Fnd = Range("E:E").FindNext(Fnd)
            If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Fnd.Address = fAdr Then Exit Do
            Fnd.Value = "#N/A"
        Loop
    End If
    Set Fnd = Range("I:I").Find(Wrds(i), , , xlPart, , , False)
    If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then
        fAdr = Fnd.Address
        Fnd.Value = "#N/A"
        Do
            Set Fnd = Range("I:I").FindNext(Fnd)
            If Fnd Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If Fnd.Address = fAdr Then Exit Do
            Fnd.Value = "#N/A"
        Loop
    End If
Next i

Range("E:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you've encountered is `Range.Areas`. In your case, the `.SpecialCells` function has created a number of `Areas` and one or more of those areas overlap. For example, if any of your rows had an error in more than one column, then you'd have overlapping areas (ie two or more areas all containing the same row). You cannot run a `Delete` method on overlapping areas.

There are many ways to deal with this issue, but a simple one-liner would be to `Intersect` the sheet's cells with your range. That kind of coerces Excel to remove overlaps.

So your last line could simply be:

```
Intersect(Sheet1.Cells, Sheet1.Range("E:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow).Delete
```

You'll note I've qualified the ranges by using the worksheet object. You might want to follow that protocol as it prevents code inadvertently running on an incorrect worksheet.

Incidentally, if you're only interested in columns "E" and "I", then your range definition would be as follows:

```
Intersect(Sheet1.Cells, Sheet1.Range("E:E,I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow).Delete
```

Answer (score 7):

I cam across this error when trying to delete entire rows with columns that were hidden. I had the program unhide the columns before attempting the Entirerow.delete and that worked for me.