# VBA change Extensions range - Cannot use that command on overlapping selections

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that works

```
Sub EXPORT_POR()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FileSaveName As Variant

FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text (Tab delimited) (*.*), *.*")

Sheets("POR_FINAL_OU").Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With wb
    With ws
        .Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.DELETE
        .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
    End With
    .SaveAs FileSaveName, xlTextWindows
    .Close False
End With

i = MsgBox("Soubor uložen", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)

End Sub
```

Now I have extended the sheet with additional columns and thus logically extended the code

```
Sub EXPORT_POR()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim FileSaveName As Variant

FileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text (Tab delimited) (*.*), *.*")

Sheets("POR_FINAL_OU").Copy
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

With wb
    With ws
        .Range("A:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.DELETE
        .Range(.Cells(1, "G"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
    End With
    .SaveAs FileSaveName, xlTextWindows
    .Close False
End With

i = MsgBox("Soubor uložen", vbOKOnly + vbInformation)

End Sub
```

Now I get the following error when I start macro

"error 1004 - Cannot use that command on overlapping selections"

I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA Excel - Cannot use that command on overlapping selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55754202/vba-excel-cannot-use-that-command-on-overlapping-selections)

Answer (score 0):

i solved this way. Juste change this:

```
With ws
    .Range("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.DELETE
    .Range(.Cells(1, "G"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)).Clear
End With
.SaveAs FileSaveName, xlTextWindows
.Close False
```